# GCP VM instances schedule is not starting the attached instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Last Friday I've updated daily start/stop [schedule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop) for an instance (deleted previous one and created a new one with different timing).

The instance was not changed. It's a preemptible e2-medium instance.

For some reason the schedule did not starting the VM, I also don't see any logs from it.

I did not change the permission, but just to be sure I've confirmed that the Google APIs Service Agent still has the standard Editor permission.

No other changes were made anywhere on this GCP.

I've tried to create other schedules with CRON expressions, different timezones, different instances, tried setting the initiation date. None of this worked.

The schedule zone is us-central, the instance zone is us-central1-a.

I've tried to wait for 15 minutes and more.

Comment: Add this predefined “Compute Instance Admin (v1)” role or any equivalent role (custom role if needed) that contains the permission “compute.instances.start” and “compute.instances.stop” to the Compute Engine Service Agent “service-863880100261@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com” and add the instances to the instance schedule.

Comment: correction to your idea: this is your GCP service account. You were talking about "Google APIs Service Agent" most likely. I tried adding that permission to it even though it is already "Editor". No difference.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was indeed caused by the missing permission. I had to give permission compute.instances.start to the right account

- `service-<my-gcp-numeric-id>@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com”` <- this one
- `<my-gcp-numeric-id>@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`. <- not this one

But what's interesting is:

1. Previously (a year ago) created schedules worked fine.
2. The above mentioned account (`service-<my-gcp-numeric-id>@`) is not displayed anywhere, even after I given it persmissions.
3. When I create schedule on a brand new project it complains about that account missing the permission and doesn't let me attach instances, but in the original case there were no error messages.

Comment: In the Google Cloud Console GUI for IAM, there is a checkbox to display Google managed service accounts.